# Prove that the function $F ( z ) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{c_n z^n}{n!}$ is analytic on the whole $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{D} → \mathbb{D}$ be an analytic function with Taylor series $f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_nz^n.$ Prove that the function
$F ( z ) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{c_n z^n}{n!}$
is analytic on the whole $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e., is entire) and satisfies the inequality $|F (z)| ≤ e^{|z|}$
for all $z ∈ \mathbb{C}.$

This is an old qual problem in Complex Analysis.  I am at a loss on how to begin.  I would appreciate some help.  Thank you.

Comment: No.  In that case $f$ is not a function $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$  So that is not a counter-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ is $\geqslant 1$, you have

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \lvert c_n\rvert^{1/n} \leqslant 1,$$

which immediately yields the infinite radius of convergence for the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{n!}z^n.$$

To obtain the inequality $\lvert F(z)\rvert \leqslant e^{\lvert z\rvert}$, the simplest way is to show that $\lvert c_n\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all $n$, which follows from the fact that $f$ maps the unit disk to itself, and Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives.

Comment: Okay.  So I showed everything you suggested.  But how is it clear now that $|F(z)| \leq e^{|z|}?$

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.